# Python Open Source Development

Tags: python, open-source, github

I am looking to contribute to some Python projects on Github, and I am looking for a bit of clarification on the mechanics of doing this effectively.  As I understand it, the typical workflow is as follows:

1. Fork the repository you would like to contribute to.
2. Clone the your forked repository.
3. Create a Python virtual environment and install / locally import your repo. My understanding is that this portion is needed to ensure the module you are looking to contribute to is the one from Github, and not the one already installed on your machine.
4. Develop, test, etc. your intended changes.
5. Commit back to Github.
6. Submit pull requests to have your changes incorporated into the parent project.

While I'm looking for confirmation overall, I'm looking for confirmation regarding Step 3 primarily as my understanding at this point remains a bit grey.

Comment: What do you mean by §3 and why? You usually don't need any "virtual environment" to develop software! At least edit your question to explain what you mean!

Comment: Absolutely - And this could be a misunderstanding on my part.  For example, if I wanted to contribute to [sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn), how to I contribute to the most recent code I pulled from Github, rather than the sklearn module already installed on my machine?  My understanding is that python virtual environments were the solution to this problem, but I could certainly be wrong.

Comment: You should edit your question, please, with your example. It probably is a matter of setting some `PATH` (or equivalent thing).... And it is probably operating system specific. So improve your question by editing it. BTW you probably don't want to change system-wide your settings

Comment: Do the clarifications provided add the needed context?  Perhaps you could explain your steps for contributing to Python open source.  I use a mac and am somewhat familiar with editing PATH variables.  Are you implying that the steps would entail cloning the repo and modifying the PATH variable to point to the clone, as opposed to creating a virtual environment?

Comment: This workflow is basically correct. There isn't much else to say that doesn't involve diving into the specifics of Github, git, virtualenv, pip, etc. Stack Exchange sites are better at solving individual questions than general mentoring. There are "developer mentor" sites that might be able to help you further.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch “virtual environments” are perhaps most urgent with Ruby: different language versions are slightly incompatible, so you need to specify the version on a per-project basis rather than using the same version system-wide – there is no `--std=c++11` flag. More importantly, when working on a project you want the exact dependencies available and no other packages, or you might accidentally introduce invisible dependencies or bugs from using a wrong package version. (Note that many languages have their own package manager such as `pip` for Python) […]

Comment: […] Many languages therefore have scripts that help isolate different projects. They automatically load the correct language version and package library for each project, and therefore create a separate “virtual environment” for each project. This is more lightweight than using a full-blown VM for development. Ruby has RVM and rbenv, Python has [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html), Perl has perlbrew and plenv, … does C++ have something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is check how projects accept submissions and in what format (e.g. where to branch from, do you need to rebase, style guide etc.). Make that step 0.

For step 3, it depends on your workflow. Mine is to clone the repo to a folder I have specially for such projects, create a virtualenv (usually using virtualenvwrapper, as it makes creating new virtualenvs easy, especially useful for testing that installing still works), install any build/dev requirements not listed in the setup.py (the readme/documentation should say what these are), then install the project in editable mode (running `pip install -e .` ). See https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html#usage for how to get started using virtualenv.

Note that this may not work for every package (typically if it cannot be installed using pip, then this will not work), in this case you could use user `site-packages` (i.e. `pip install --user` instead of `pip install`).

In the case of `sklearn`, you need to install `numpy` and `scipy` into the virtualenv before installing `sklearn`. Make sure to do the `numpy` install separately to scipy, `pip install numpy scipy` won't work.

Finally, step 3 will vary for every developer, it's best to develop your own workflow. The main thing is to make sure that any changes are acceptable to the project.